# Atalho para "console.log()" no VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Existe, no Visual Studio Code, uma forma de inserir `console.log()` assim que começo a escrever? Ou então um atalho do teclado?

Answer (score 1):

Revirando o VS code, vi que ao digitar 'log', aparece a previsão de console.log(). deve servir pra outros que precisam de algo parecido.

Answer (score 1):

- Digite 'log'  e aperte a tecla 'tab' (log + tab).
- Caso não funcione, quando digitar 'log' escolha a opção que aparecerá 'log log to the console' e tente de novo.